# Struts2 CRUD Delete not Working

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, struts, crud

I am trying to delete a selected row in a project where I'm using Hibernate and Struts.

```
<a href="DeletePublication?Id=<s:property value="Id"/>"><img
                    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/delete.png" width=20px
                    height=20px></a>
```

This is the Link I want to Click! In the `struts.xml` the Action is defined as:

```
    <action name="DeletePublication" class="de.nak.library.action.PublicationAction"
        method="delete">
        <result type="redirect">ShowPublicationList.action</result>
        <result type="chain" name="input">ShowPublicationList</result>
    </action>
```

The Action class looks like:

```
    public String delete() {
    publication = publicationService.loadPublication(publicationId);
    if (publication != null) {
        publicationService.deletePublication(publication);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
```

If I click the link, nothing is happening! I tried to set a breakpoint in the `delete` method, and I saw that it is not even called. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in the `struts.xml`:

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
```

This will turn on a developer mode where you can see more log messages on the console. You might not have getter and setter for properties. Missing `"` in the attributes.

```
<s:a namespace="onthepackage" action="DeletePublication"><s:param name="Id" value="%{Id}"/><img
     src="<s:url value='/img/delete.png'/>" width="20px"
     height="20px">
</s:a>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! i turn the devMode on, still no useful error! i tried your code example, unfortunately with no effect :( the url is correct, but the method is still not called. and there are getters and setters...

Comment: Post a complete `struts.xml`.

Comment: thank you! i found the erro, it was a typo in a setter :( SO STUPID MISTAKE!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `<a href="">` directly, use `<s:url>` to get to the `DeletePublication` action. Then use that `<s:url>`'s reference to `<a href='<s:property value="#ref"/>'`.